# JAX: Getting rid of zero-gradient

Tags: python, math, derivative, jax, google-jax

Is there a way how to modify this function (MyFunc) so that it gives the same result, but its derivative is not zero gradient?

```
from jax import grad
import jax.nn as nn
import numpy as np

def MyFunc(coefs):
   a = coefs[0]
   b = coefs[1]
   c = coefs[2]
   
   if a > b:
      return 30.0
   elif b > c:
      return 20.0
   else:
      return 10.0   
   
myFuncDeriv = grad (MyFunc)   

# prints [0. 0. 0.]
print (myFuncDeriv(np.random.sample(3)))
# prints [0. 0. 0.]
print (myFuncDeriv(np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])))
```

EDIT: Similar function which doesn't give zero gradient - but it doesn't return 30/20/10

```
def MyFunc2(coefs):
    a = coefs[0]
    b = coefs[1]
    c = coefs[2]
    if a > b:
        return nn.sigmoid(a)*30.0
    if b > c:
        return nn.sigmoid(b)*20.0
    else:
        return nn.sigmoid(c)*10.0


myFunc2Deriv = grad (MyFunc2)   

# prints [0.         0.         0.45176652]
print (myFuncDeriv(np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])))
# prints for example [6.1160526 0.        0.       ]
print (myFunc2Deriv(np.random.sample(3)))
```

Comment: Please add an example with non-random arguments and the expected non-zero gradient for these values.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny OK, I tried to modify my original post. But expected non-zero gradient: I have no idea what that should be, I don't care what the gradients are - except I don't want it to be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient of your function is zero because this is the correct result for the gradient as your function is defined. For more information on this phenomenon, see [FAQ: Why are gradients zero for functions based on sort order?](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-are-gradients-zero-for-functions-based-on-sort-order)

If you want a sort-based function with non-zero gradients, you can achieve this by replacing your step-wise function with a smooth approximation. The sigmoid version you included in your question seems like a reasonable approach for this approximation.

But note that the answer to your exact question – how to make a function that produces the same output but has nonzero gradients – is impossible, because a function returning the same outputs as yours for all inputs has a zero gradient by definition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I understand it correctly - the ideal approximation (better than sigmoid) would be if I had a function which returns y=1 for any value of x, except for x very close to zero, e.g. 0.00000001 and -000000001, in which case it returns y=0.999999999 ?